# El contenido de main se sube a la altura del header

Tags: html, css

Me gustaría saber ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el contenido de `main` se coloque abajo, sin tener que quitar la propiedad de position fix del `header`? Quiero que permanezca mientras hago scroll para abajo.

Añado el código de `css` también:

```
      <header> <!-- inicio header -->
        <div class="div-nav">
        <nav class="nav-bar">
        <a href="#">Inicio</a>
        <a href="#">Banquetes</a>
        <img class="logo" src="/Imagenes/logo.png" alt="logo.png">
        <a href="#">Menú</a>
                 <a href="#">Contacto</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header> <!-- fin header -->
    
    <main> <!-- inicio main -->
    
<section class="section-h2">
<h2>No te quedes con el antojo!</h2>
<button class="boton-contacto">Contactar</button>
</section>
```

Este es mi código de `css`:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.logo{
    width: 150px;
}

.div-nav{
    height: 500px;
}

.nav-bar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mí, la opción más cómoda sería utilizar `position: sticky`, ya que colocaría automáticamente el contenido de `main` justo debajo de `header`, mida lo que mida éste.

```css
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red; /* Sólo para el test */
}

.main {
  min-height: 700px; /* Sólo para el test */
  background: green; /* Sólo para el test */
}
```

```html
<header class="header">Cabecera</div></header>
<main class="main">Contenido principal</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es agregarle un `padding-top` a `main` de la misma altura que tu `header` (Que por cierto pusiste `500px` y creo que es mucho, lo reduje en el ejemplo al igual que la altura de `.div-nav`).

Ejemplo:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}

.logo{
    width: 150px;
}

.div-nav{
    height: 40px;
}

.nav-bar{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

main {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header> <!-- inicio header -->
    <div class="div-nav">
        <nav class="nav-bar">
            <a href="#">Inicio</a>
            <a href="#">Banquetes</a>
            <img class="logo" src="/Imagenes/logo.png" alt="logo.png">
            <a href="#">Menú</a>
            <a href="#">Contacto</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header> <!-- fin header -->
    
<main> <!-- inicio main -->
    <section class="section-h2">
        <h2>No te quedes con el antojo!</h2>
        <button class="boton-contacto">Contactar</button>
    </section>
</main>
```